# How to download (raw) logs for Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can I download the logs for Firebase Cloud Functions?

I am able to view them in the console (via: project > functions > logs tab). Is there a convenient way to download/retrieve all of (or an interval of time for) these logs?

Thanks.